# How to get header values from ascii file with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file, in particular, I want to read a specific column of it. The problem is that the header has four columns while the data has two columns. How can I do this in Python? The file that I'm trying to read look like this

```
 96564      330       11     1                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                                                        1.276179694473037E+00    1.666387732294628E+00
  -1.7567416009136452E-004  -2.1164129099324222E-003   2.1490310576924058E-005  -2.7620298845456630       -1.8938557128664963        8.1451380842752732E-002   5.6798992969198242E-003
  -2.4287971047070860E-005  -2.3609881614543712E-003   3.1144023010759590E-005   4.0745088882476184       0.33917759997860736        1.4630230584405567E-002   1.3515126501174172E-003
   5.1771204588632223E-004  -2.3859807510696008E-003   4.5398813079852952E-005  0.45840350786923445        2.6436923397475449        3.1001309161949490E-002   1.3304268623415794E-003
   2.0168729283814068E-003  -2.8511940463213253E-003   6.1138543197632175E-005   2.8865136613288249        2.2963200558859995        3.3124888426326403E-002   1.2587884928308795E-003
  -2.1486254552195442E-004  -2.1629086122666023E-003   1.3836748439773666E-005   7.7251215411289289        1.7052985468843680      -0.78855585945347717        6.8568153674527599E-004
   5.0931650983650221E-006  -2.3443067492165833E-003   2.5411108135731121E-005  0.23718439736076949        5.8967883591361314       0.48056164762398068        7.2087010119962060E-004
   1.9187225151669921E-003  -2.1025090182238706E-003   8.8987477328659638E-005 -0.25318942890334173        1.9430755960869355        4.6912070943073196E-002   1.4532354957884940E-003
  -3.7740008788295651E-004  -2.6810238020915111E-003   3.3177567534301046E-005   3.9967795229052840       0.41588955059533705       -3.3938217242456201E-002   7.8802206461770473E-004
   8.8238186001925103E-004  -5.0404770964643329E-004   5.9745726301358809E-005  -2.5028283387987362        1.2005940373166184      -0.30136573399772792        7.4708585346873338E-004
  -1.8595757572406899E-003  -2.7475038056757380E-003   2.5570423015501202E-005  -5.4697141814638035E-002  -2.6754750580122764       -6.6391158401522363E-002   1.0234052787242941E-003
  -3.5376590824452540E-004  -4.1009265163613976E-003  -8.1420707166233811E-006   1.9466623872113207      -0.10603400063515293      -0.29897526568706323        1.6929128358203331E-004
```

Comment: I've tried to format your question a bit better, but the result doesn't seem to agree with your statement that your data has only 2 columns. Can you please check, and either revert the edit or adjust the edit if necessary?

Comment: Can't you just edit the file, and remove the extra headers? It doesn't make sense anyway to have 4 headers and only 2 data columns anyway; essentially, that means the data file is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    arr = line.split()
    if len(arr) == 4:   # 4 column so this is header
      continue
    # do whatever after if statement
```